# Codeigniter upload data from Excel and define a column

Tags: php, mysql, excel, codeigniter

I am trying to upload data from Excel and automatically define a column in my database based on the Excel data.

Example: if the "Transaction" column is > 10000$, then "Note" column is automatically "Suspicious". I've tried this code, but it won't work.

This is my controller:

```
  for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){                
            $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                            NULL,
                                            TRUE,
                                            FALSE);


            $data= array(
                "transaction"=> $rowData[0][1]  
                "note"=> *i need something here*                     

            ); 

            if ($this->input->post("transaction") >= 10000){
             $data->note = "suspicious";
             }
            else{
             $data->note = "unsuspicious";
            }

            $insert = $this->db->insert("info",$data);
            delete_files($config['file_path'],TRUE);

        }
```

Any suggestion for my $data = array();
or should i put the condition in another place?

Comment: Since $data is an array use it like, $data['note'] instead of $data->note.

Answer (score 0):

`$data` array structure was incorrect, you missed a comma after `'transaction'` key.

```
 $data = array(
     "transaction"=> $rowData[0][1],  
     "note"=> ""                     
 );
```

Since `$data` is an array do not use `$data->note`, instead that use `$data['note']`

```
if ($this->input->post("transaction") >= 10000){
    $data['note'] = "suspicious";
} else{
    $data['note'] = "unsuspicious";
}
```